# Can one receive initiation from a (physically) dead GURU?

Tags: guru, initiation

Can one receive , in some way, initiation by a Guru who is physically dead even in absence of His/ Her Disciples ( if they exist)?????

Within ISKCON and Gaudyia Math one can find  the example of Srila Prabhuapada Bhaktisiddhanta Saraswati who considered himself initiated as a sannyasi by Gaura Kishor Das Babaji as he took sannyasa after a dream near 1918 .

Now not all the Gaudya Vaishnava do accept this procedure and many in Vrindavana reject GM and ISKCON Teachings. Indeed in  Sri Isana Nagara’s Advaita Prakasa (8.118-122) it is described how Sita-devi, the consort of Advaita Prabhu, received initiation in a dream from Srila Madhavendra Puri, but that Advaita Prabhu still found it necessary to give her a concrete, audible initiation.

But let us forget ISKCOn peculiar beliefs and  imagine the case of a Guru who has not left any official Lineage of Disciples , like Shirdi Sai Baba or Anandamayi Ma.

If I consider such a Person as My Guru how can I receive initiation from Him or Her? Actually I am sure that many holy Gurus did not leave an 'official' Parampara after their Final Samadhi.

Comment: "But let us forget ISKCOn peculiar beliefs" that is hard for me and the same goes for the Gaudiya Vaishnavas. Their beliefs are cherry picked, they twist scriptures, they make up rituals and thus are very peculiar.

Comment: although your question is opinion based, there are many people that have had in different hindu traditions.

Answer (score 1):

In SPIRITUAL realm, everything does not happen, as laid down in the scriptures,ie., initiation by a Physical guru, practice under him/her, etc.

[Sri Ramadasu aka Kancharla Gopanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhadrachala_Ramadasu) (కంచర్ల గోపన్న) (c. 1620 – 1680), was a 17th-century Indian devotee of Lord Rama and a composer of Carnatic music.

[It is believed that **Saint Kabir**](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/hindu-saint-jailed-for-12-years), when initiated him into the realms of spirituality, gave him the name Ramadasa. Since Kabir lived a few centuries before Ramadasa, scholars believe that the initiation happened in a dream.

---

The dead Guru, whom the OP wants to consider as Guru, may give initiation in dream/in person or may direct to another living Guru.  There is no laid down rule for that thing to happen.

The prerequisite is ripening of one's practice.

Comment: Very interesting historical example! Thank you!